# Since Cassandra has no transactions and all statements are atomic, how can rollbacks be simulated if needed?

Tags: java, cassandra

If I have two different tables (maybe to represent two different queries) and I need to keep them in sync, if I update a value in the first table and then an error occurs while updating the second table, how would i rollback the first table's update?

Example:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sample.hotels (
  id UUID,
  name varchar,
  address varchar,
  state varchar,
  zip varchar,
  primary key((id), name)
 );

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sample.hotels_by_letter (
  first_letter varchar,
  hotel_name varchar,
  hotel_id UUID,
  address varchar,
  state varchar,
  zip varchar,
  primary key((first_letter), hotel_name, hotel_id)
 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra does support batch statements for this kind of use: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html

This will guarantee that all statements in the batch will either all succeed or all fail. Outside of this, there is no ability to rollback a transaction.

Comment: You're probably correct but the wording doesn't mention failure of a part leading to failure of the other statements, only success. It's odd wording: `Batches are atomic by default. In the context of a Cassandra batch operation, atomic means that if any of the batch succeeds, all of it will.`

Comment: If any of it succeeds, it all will. So, if one of them didn't succeed (failed), that means none of them succeeded (failed). Agree wording can be more explicit.